# How to remove tty[7-63]?

Tags: linux, debian, tty

I have an embedded system, a beaglebone black to be specific. This SBC runs Debian wheezy 7.4, and a custom 3.8.x kernel. Patched for this hardware. Anyway, the title pretty much says it all. I can disable tty[1-6] From within /etc/inittab. This is fairly well documented all over the web, and honestly really hard not to stumble across while exploring the system.

However, I have scoured the web the best I can, and can not find much information about tty[7-63]. I am starting to get a feeling this may be a kernel config option, but I am not sure. I did read the documentation for kernel boot time options, and saw nothing there to indicate this.

Can anyone shed some light on this subject for me ?